# Does the property of exclusiveTouch affect the sub views?

Tags: iphone, ios

When I set a view's `exclusiveTouch` property to YES, will any added subviews be affected or not? Or, it only means the view is exclusive to touch, but the added subview will receive multi-touch when its `exclusiveTouch` is NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying, if the view's `exclusiveTouch` is set to YES, it doesn't affect the added sub views behavior about exclusive touch.